# Is there a way to provide a specific hostname to an application that differs from the machine hostname on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, dns

Is there a way to provide a specific hostname to an application that differs from the machine hostname on Linux?  Basically, I have a piece of software that expects the local machine to have a certain hostname that differs from my machine hostname.  Rather than change the machine hostname globally, I'd like a mechanism where I can either run the program in an environment with the specified hostname or run the program directly with the specified hostname.

Comment: How is the hostname used in the program?  For DNS purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible with root privileges. Use **`unshare --uts`** to create a new UTS<sup>1</sup> namespace, set the desired hostname in it, then `su` back to your account and run the app. For example:

```
ongun@foo$ sudo -s
~ create a new namespace ~
root@foo# unshare --uts /bin/sh
~ this terminal now has its own namespace – change the hostname ~
root@foo# hostname quux
~ switch back ~
root@quux# sudo -s -u ongun
ongun@quux$ /usr/bin/game
```

Namespaces are limited to their creator process by default, so the new hostname will be visible only to programs you run *inside* the "unshare"d window.

**Note:** Don't forget to actually add the new hostname to `/etc/hosts` as 127.0.0.1, as many programs expect / depend on it to be resolvable.

---

<sup>1</sup> Don't ask what "UTS" means. Best I know is it's a leftover from ancient Unix.

Comment: If the program only needs to resolve the hostname, then you would only need to modify /etc/hosts, no need to create a new namespace. This is slightly more secure as you only need root privilege once when editing /etc/hosts rather than during every application startup.

Answer (score 0):

If your application does not directly read output of `hostname` or `/etc/hostname` file, you can always create an alias for your machine like below.

```
#
# /etc/hosts: static lookup table for host names
#

#<ip-address>   <hostname.domain.org>   <hostname>
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost MYHOSTNAME   OTHER_ALIAS
::1             localhost.localdomain   localhost MYHOSTNAMEv6 OTHER_ALIASv6
```

or you can try creating a chroot with a different host name like [here](http://blog.marineau.org/post/46688543379/giving-chroot-its-own-hostname-chname)

Answer (score 0):

I presume you do not have the source code of the program in question. Reading a machine's hostname is done thru a sys call, [gethostname()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gethostname), which it would be hard to circumvent without access to the program source code.

You should then use a virtual solution to run the program. Containers, dockers, VMs have the sufficient degree of isolation to allow you to rename them to the required value, without compromising your host machine. [A container](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux_Containers) is very lightweight solution which will drain very little of your host resources.